# How to display post thumbnails from custom post type category on homepage?

Tags: custom-post-types

My site has the custom post type, "reviews" with its own categories. I would like to display post thumbnails from these categories on the homepage. The code I'm attempting to use for this is for displaying related posts. However, I will be using it on the homepage, so it's not a "review post" and doesn't have a category assigned to it.

I thought it might be possible to do a post type query, i.e: `<?php query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'reviews' )); ?>`

Here's the "related posts" code I'm using:

```
<!-- Start Related Posts -->

<?php $categories = get_the_category($post->ID); if ($categories) { 
$category_ids = array(); foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id; 
$args=array( 'category__in' => $category_ids, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), 'posts_per_page'=>4, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );

$my_query = new wp_query( $args ); if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { echo 

'<div class="related-posts">
   <div class="postauthor-top">
     <h3>'.__('Related Posts','mythemeshop').'</h3>
   </div>

   <ul>'; $counter = '0'; while( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ++$counter; if($counter == 4) { $postclass = 'last'; $counter = 0; } 

else { $postclass = ''; } 

$my_query->the_post(); $li = 1; ?>

     <li class="<?php echo $postclass; ?> relatepostli<?php echo $li+$counter; ?>">
       <a rel="nofollow" class="relatedthumb" href="<?php the_permalink()?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
         <span class="rthumb">

<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?><?php the_post_thumbnail('widgetthumb', 'title='); ?>

<?php else: ?>

           <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/smallthumb.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  width='180' height='120' class="wp-post-image" />

<?php endif; ?>

           <div class="post-number"><?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></div>
         </span>

         <span><?php the_title(); ?>
         </span>
       </a>
     </li>

<?php } echo 
  '</ul>
</div>'; }} 

wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!-- .related-posts -->
```

Comment: I think your question should be, how can i display the category description from a custom post type.

Comment: Your code is a mess and not very readable friendly, you should take your time and properly indent your code and not try to cram 10 lines into one. Most probably your question has not yet been answered due to the fact that no one can properly read your code